# How to kill a Weapon bullet that hit an enemy? Phaser 2.7.5

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi guys I’m making this simple game that consists in two players in a arena
Each player has a Weapon that shoot a projectile.
What I want is, every time that a projectile hit a block or an enemy its hp is decreased by 1 and the bullet that touched the enemy or the block disappear .

I tried use Lifespan to kill the bullet (lifespan = 0 when the bullet overlap the enemy) but no success.
I'm using `bullet.kill()` but it seems not working too.

How i made the weapon:

```
weapon = game.add.weapon(10, 'bullet');
weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;  weapon.bulletSpeed = 200;
weapon.fireRate = 1000;
weapon.trackSprite(this.player, 0, 0, false);

weapon2 = game.add.weapon(10, 'bullet');
weapon2.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;
weapon2.bulletSpeed = 200;
weapon2.fireRate = 1000;
weapon2.trackSprite(this.player2, 0, 0, false);
```

Colission:

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(weapon.bullets, this.player2, this.hitP2, null, this);
game.physics.arcade.overlap(weapon.bullets, this.blocks, this.hitBlock1, null, this);

game.physics.arcade.overlap(weapon2.bullets, this.player, this.hitP1, null, this);
game.physics.arcade.overlap(weapon2.bullets, this.blocks, this.hitBlock2, null, this);
```

Hit functions:

```
hitBlock: function(bul, blk){

        bul.kill();
},

hitP: function(bul, enm){

        // sfx de acerto

        p1HP -= 1;

        this.txtP1HP.text = 'P1 HP: ' + p1HP;

        bul.kill();

        if(p1HP < 1){

            this.player.kill();
}, this);
```

What happens now is, when the bullet hit the enemy he becomes invisible and the bullet still running until get out of bounds.

Why the kill method doesn't work properly in this one?
Why the enemy becomes invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Phaser but I'm interested, so, by checking [the overlap docs](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#overlap) it states:

> The two objects will be passed to this function in the same order in which you specified them, unless you are checking Group vs. Sprite, in which case Sprite will always be the first parameter.

You declare overlap with a group apparently, so you need to swap your arguments, the sprite will always be the first parameter. The player disappeared because you killed it instead of the bullet:

```
hitBlock: function(blk, bul){ //instead of (bul, blk)

    bul.kill();

},

hitP: function(enm, bul){ //instead of (bul, enm)

    // sfx de acerto

    p1HP -= 1;

    this.txtP1HP.text = 'P1 HP: ' + p1HP;

    bul.kill();

    if(p1HP < 1){
        this.player.kill();
    }

}
```

I'm not sure it will effectively kill the bullet though, because the second parameter could be a bullet group instead of the one that effectively overlaps.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Man, you saved me. I don't saw this implementation detail in the docs. It solved my problem at'all, thanks !

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help! This framework seems fun